# How do I get ffmpeg to correctly output this wav file?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, concatenation, wav

I'm trying to concatenate a lot of wav files and it far exceeds the 4GB limit.

Someone mentioned somewhere that the `-rf64 auto option` will solve it but -rf64 isn't recognized in the command line. What do I need to do in this command line to solve this problem?

```
ffmpeg -f concat -rf64 auto -i mylist.txt -c copy output.wav
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a muxer option, so

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy -rf64 auto output.wav
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand the difference it made though.

Comment: The basic syntax of a ffmpeg command is `ffmpeg options-for-input1 -i input1 options-for-input2 -i input2 options-for-output1 output1 options-for-output2 output2`. Since the output will be 4GB+, you have to tell ffmpeg that the key:value applies to the output function. Your original command tells ffmpeg that the input has a 64-bit header.